# Numpy masked_array sum

Tags: python, numpy, sum, masked-array

I would expect the result of a summation for a fully masked array to be zero, but instead "masked" is returned. How can I get the function to return zero?

```
>>> a = np.asarray([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> b = np.ma.masked_array(a, mask=~(a > 2))
>>> b
masked_array(data = [-- -- 3 4],
             mask = [ True  True False False],
       fill_value = 999999)

>>> b.sum()
7
>>> b = np.ma.masked_array(a, mask=~(a > 5))
>>> b
masked_array(data = [-- -- -- --],
         mask = [ True  True  True  True],
   fill_value = 999999)


>>> b.sum()
masked
>>> np.ma.sum(b)
masked
>>>
```

Here's another unexpected thing:

```
>>> b.sum() + 3
masked
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your last case:

```
In [197]: bs=b1.sum()
In [198]: bs.data
Out[198]: array(0.0)
In [199]: bs.mask
Out[199]: array(True, dtype=bool)
In [200]: repr(bs)
Out[200]: 'masked'
In [201]: str(bs)
Out[201]: '--'
```

If I specify `keepdims`, I get a different array:

```
In [208]: bs=b1.sum(keepdims=True)
In [209]: bs
Out[209]: 
masked_array(data = [--],
             mask = [ True],
       fill_value = 999999)
In [210]: bs.data
Out[210]: array([0])
In [211]: bs.mask
Out[211]: array([ True], dtype=bool)
```

here's the relevant part of the `sum` code:

```
def sum(self, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=np._NoValue):
    kwargs = {} if keepdims is np._NoValue else {'keepdims': keepdims}

    _mask = self._mask
    newmask = _check_mask_axis(_mask, axis, **kwargs)
    # No explicit output
    if out is None:
        result = self.filled(0).sum(axis, dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
        rndim = getattr(result, 'ndim', 0)
        if rndim:
            result = result.view(type(self))
            result.__setmask__(newmask)
        elif newmask:
            result = masked
        return result
    ....
```

It's the

```
 newmask = np.ma.core._check_mask_axis(b1.mask, axis=None)
 ...
 elif newmask: result = masked
```

lines that produce the `masked` value in your case.  `newmask` is True in the case where all values are masked, and False is some are not.  The choice to return `np.ma.masked` is deliberate.

The core of the calculation is:

```
In [218]: b1.filled(0).sum()
Out[218]: 0
```

the rest of the code decides whether to return a scalar or masked array.

============

And for your addition:

```
In [232]: np.ma.masked+3
Out[232]: masked
```

It looks like the `np.ma.masked` is a special array that propagates itself across calculations.  Sort of like `np.nan`.

Comment: I'd expect a scalar value to be returned, not an array (it's the sum over all dimensions that I am looking for).

Comment: I added the relevant part of the `sum` code.  I can understand why there might be some ambiguity in the returned value when the input is fully masked.  I'm not privy to any debates as to whether this is right or not.  If you don't like the result you could apply sum to `b.filled(0)`.

Comment: Looks like the reasoning is, 'if all values are masked, it can't give a proper scalar value (even if the starting value of the sum is 0)`.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for digging this up. You comparison with `np.nan` is spot on. I guess I can always do `b.filled(0).sum()` as you wrote.

Comment: @hpaulj yes, because I think the reasoning behind and one of the main point of the masked arrays that appears from the documentation and a recurring word in there is "invalid" and a scalar, for example 0, might be a valid returned value in general. So probably they try to be cautious.

Comment: @fedepad @hpaulj: I get that they treat it similar to `np.nan`, but then there should be a special `sum()` function like `nansum()`.